# Number of solutions to a Linear equation $a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-2) + a_3(x-3) + . . . +a_{x-1} = x$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-2) + a_3(x-3) + . . . +a_{x-1} = x$$
Where $a_i = (1 \quad or \quad 0)$

I was thinking if there exists some solution that takes only O($N$) linear time computation.

Comment: Can you look at your sum again i don't think the last term is $a_{x-1}$. If it is i don't understand what terms are in the "+...+". Also, what is the relation between the number of solutions (question in title) and computation time?

Comment: I missed that $a_i$ is either 0 or 1. So what I want to count  the number of ways a number X can be represented as sum of values lesser than X, without repetition.